# ReactJS - How to remove whole component , by using child button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have problem , i want to create TODO app in ReactJS and there is functionality like this:

1. onClick is showing/hidding AddTaskBox (form in div, where you have to write title and describtion ) - I done it.
2. In visable AddTaskBox is button with "x" and I want to use him to delete whole "AddTaskBox" - Can't figur it out :(

I'm greeny in React , my thinking about that library may be wrong.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class AddButton extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
      super();

      this.state = {
      isHidden: false
    }
  }

  toggleHidden () {
      this.setState({
        isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
      })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div
          onClick={this.toggleHidden.bind(this)}
          className="addtask__btn">
          +
        </div>
        {this.state.isHidden && <AddTaskBox />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AddTaskBox extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="addtask__box" >
        <button> x </button> // here is my x to close component
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Nazwa Czynności"/>
          <textarea>
            Opis czynności do wykonania
          </textarea>
          <input className="btn" type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export {AddButton, AddTaskBox};
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by `AddTaskComponent` you mean `AddTaskBox` you would pass the `toggleHidden` function to `AddTaskBox`

`{this.state.isHidden && <AddTaskBox onClose={this.toggleHidden.bind(this)} />}`

and then call the function from the child on click

`<button onClick={this.props.onClose}> x </button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your `toggleHidden()` function as prop to AddTasktBox component.

So your close button in AddTaskBox will be like

```
...
<button onClick={this.props.handleClick}> x </button>
...
```

You can pass it like

```
{this.state.isHidden && <AddTaskBox handleClick={this.toggleHidden.bind(this)} />}
```